# UltrVNC repeater with HTML5 client (Guacamole?) support

Tags: ubuntu, html5-canvas, vnc-server, guacamole

We currently have devices out in the field running UltraVNC as a VNC server. Because we have devices out in the field with non-routable IP addresses we opted to go with an UltraVNC repeater server.

VNC is started on the device and we have a java applet running on the website that connects to the relay server. This works for us and we can have more than one session running at any given time via the repeater server(but not on the same device). We want to replace the applet with a HTML5 solution because not everybody wants to use the Java applet.

Will Guacamole work for us? Currently if a user (that has permission) goes to the site, they will see a link and if they click on it a pop-up is triggered with the applet inside it. If the service is started on the device a remote support session is started.

Will Guacamole work with the relay server? Some of the devices run on Windows CE6 and some on the Windows 7 CE (I cannot remember what they called this Windows 7 build, it is the CE version)

Is there a better solution available with no cost? I have access to an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server to load the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Guacamole supports UVNC reflector.

Comment: Gregor, is UVNC reflector the same as a VNC repeater? Where can I find more info? We currently have a VNC repeater server running and the end goal is to get rid of the Java applet viewer on the website and replace it with an HTML5 solution.